# Recognizing Word Inside message.content discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

How do i get the bot to send a message if a word inside of the sentence triggers it? Similar to `@client.event async def on_message(message) if message.content == "MESSAGE": await message.channel.send("MESSAGE")`

*I basically want it to recognize something like* `Quack comes from a duck **BOT**:`

Triggers the word duck.

Comment: Have you even googled your question? I can find an answer in less than a minute...

Comment: I have yes but nothing comes up :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: I don't understand, sorry

Comment: As @ŁukaszKwieciński said, you can simply find an answer online, let's search with google  "python in keyword", you'll understand.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for a substring inside a string, you can use the membership operator `in`. For your code:

```
@client.event 
async def on_message(message): 
    if "duck" in message.content.lower():    # lower() is used so that every case of duck will trigger it.
        await message.channel.send("MESSAGE")
```