# Filter elements in a list not containing multiple substrings in Python

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

For a list of file names `file_names`, I try to use code below to filter file names **not containing** `foo` or `bar`:

```
file_names = ['foo_data.xlsx', 'bar_data.xlsx', 'data.xlsx']
subs = ['foo', 'bar']

for file_name in file_names:
    for sub in subs:
        if sub not in file_name:
            print(file_name)
```

Output:

```
foo_data.xlsx
bar_data.xlsx
data.xlsx
data.xlsx
```

But it's not working out, it should return `data.xlsx`.

Meanwhile, it works for **containing** case:

```
file_names = ['foo_data.xlsx', 'bar_data.xlsx', 'data.xlsx']
subs = ['foo', 'bar']

for file_name in file_names:
    for sub in subs:
        if sub in file_name:
            print(file_name)
```

Out:

```
foo_data.xlsx
bar_data.xlsx
```

Does someone could help to explain what's error in my code and how to fix it? Thanks.

**Reference:**

[Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want any `sub` to be in the file names; one way is to wrap the inner loop with `all`:

```py
for file_name in file_names:
    if all(sub not in file_name for sub in subs):
        print(file_name)
```

Output:

```py
data.xlsx
```

Answer (score 1):

One regex approach would be to form an alternation of the blacklist substrings, then use `re.search` and a list comprehension to find the matches.

```py
file_names = ['foo_data.xlsx', 'bar_data.xlsx', 'data.xlsx']
subs = ['foo', 'bar']
regex = r'(?:' + '|'.join(subs) + r')'
matches = [f for f in file_names if not re.search(regex, f)]
print(matches)  # ['data.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file_names = ['foo_data.xlsx', 'bar_data.xlsx', 'data.xlsx']
subs = ['foo', 'bar']

file_names1 = []

for i in range(len(file_names)): 
    if file_names[i].startswith(subs[0])==False and file_names[i].startswith(subs[1])==False:
        file_names1.append(file_names[i])

print(file_names1)
```

Out:

```
['data.xlsx']
```

This should work having result in file_names1.

Comment: Please note it's not obligatory to startswith or endswith elements in `subs`.

Comment: Okay, but seems like this method had solution