# scrape script tag with python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, python-requests-html, python-regex

I want scrape this string "O email não é válido." from this script tag

```
$(function() {
                ,messages: {
                        "resetPasswordEmail": {
                                required: "O email é de preenchimento obrigatório."
                                ,remote: "O email não é válido."
                        }
        });
});
```

I try many of solution but its not work

```py
script = soup.find_all('script')
#print(script)
for item in script:
    if 'remote' in item.string:
        print('Validoooo')
    else:
        print('nooooooooo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Since what you are checking for is just a "does this string exist in this other string", you could simply check if your input contains the substring "O email não é válido" you can find out more on how to do this in this post: [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

If you still want to use regex, I would use something like this:

```
isMatch = soup.match("remote: *\"O email não é válido\.\"")
if isMatch:
        print('Validoooo')
    else:
        print('nooooooooo')
```

I don't know where you get the input string, but it looks like some kind of server response? If there is more data like eg. status codes, you should use those instead of language specific checks for strings in response.