# How to find if the given strings can be found inside the second strings

Tags: python

I would like to know how to write a function that returns `True` if the first string, regardless of position, can be found within the second string by using two strings taken from user input. Also by writing the code, it should not be case sensitive; by using `islower()` or `isupper()`.

Example Outputs:

> 1st String: lol
>
> 2nd String: Hilol
>
> True

> 1st String: IDK
>
> 2nd String: whatidk
>
> True

My code:

```
a1 = str(input("first string: "))
a2 = str(input("second string: "))

if a2 in a1: 
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

It outputs:

> 1st String: lol
>
> 2nd String: lol
>
> True

> 1st String: lol
>
> 2nd String: HIlol
>
> False #This should be true, IDK why it is false.

I only came this far with my code. Hoping someone could teach me what to do.

Comment: Hint: Which string should be in which?

Comment: How did you arrive at the conclusion that `HIlol` is itself a substring of `lol`? Wouldn’t that be the other way around?

Comment: OH I FOUND OUT THAT MY COULD SHOULD BE OTHER WAY AROUND, NOT a2 in a1, but a1 in a2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Python have a string 'contains' substring method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method)

Comment: *print(a1 in a2)*

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
string_1 = input("first string: ")
string_2 = input("second string: ")
print(string_1.lower() in string_2.lower())
```

A "function" would be:

```py
def check_occuring(substring, string):
    return substring.lower() in string.lower()

string_1 = input("first string: ")
string_2 = input("second string: ")
print(check_occuring(string_1, string_2))
```

Comment: Why the explicit test? Just: *return substring.lower() in string.lower()*

Answer (score 0):

If you want the Program to be case sensitive, just make everything lowercase

```py
substring = input("substring: ").lower()
text = input("text: ").lower()
```

To check if a substring can be found in another string can be done by using the keyword `in`

```
>>> "lol" in "HIlol"
True
```

maybe check your inputs here. The whole program would be

```py
substring = input("substring: ").lower()
text = input("text: ").lower()

print(substring in text)
```

*note:* `<str> in <str>` gives you a boolean so you can use it in if conditions. In this case you can just print the boolean directly.