# Why is Python startwith() not running?

Tags: python

Please tell me what's wrong with this code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/upveR.png)

Please tell me what's wrong with this code

Comment: `startswith()` - Note the extra 's'. See [the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please give a [mre], as text, when posting on SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour] and reading [ask].

Comment: The reason SO doesn't allow you to make short questions is to force you to elaborate on the problem. Like explaining what are you trying to do, what's the expected output, what's happening (_is wrong_ is **not** an actual question). So, please don't try to bypass it by duplicating your question.

Comment: you can use the ```in operetor```. Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437059/does-python-have-a-string-contains-substring-method

Comment: or split the string and check if ```https://``` exists.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote startwith instead of "startswith".

You missed the the "s" after "start"