# How do I check if a given Python string is a substring of another one?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have two strings and I would like to check whether the first is a substring of the other. Does Python have such a built-in functionality?

Comment: It is already answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590503/how-to-find-whether-a-string-in-a-another-string

Answer (score 515, accepted):

Try using `in` like this:

```
>>> x = 'hello'
>>> y = 'll'
>>> y in x
True
```

Comment: What about complexity as compare to using regex?

Answer (score 55):

Try

```
isSubstring = first in theOther
```

Answer (score 43):

`string.find("substring")` will help you. This function returns `-1` when there is no substring.

Comment: What if I was looking for the position of the third or fourth occurrence of 'e', or the likes thereof?

Comment: python supports regulary expressions (regex). What ever you are looking for make a regex-group auto of it, afterwards you can select the 3rd group.