# Arrays with loops

Tags: python, arrays, loops, token

I need to be able to write a program that takes a file then returns an array of tokens and then Loop through the array, printing each token one per line, then removes all the punctuation and lower cases each word, then counts how many times the words asked for occur throughout the file. The problem is im having trouble returning the array, I'm not quite sure how to make array that allows the user to type in any word or as many words as he want and then have the program search through the file to find those words.....ive spent 8 hrs and this is all i currently have:

```
import sys
from scanner import *


def main():
    tokens = readTokens("shakespeare.txt")
    for i in range(0,len(tokens),1):
        print(tokens[i])
def readTokens(fileName):
    with open("shakespeare.txt", 'r') as f:
        return f.read().split()
    token = s.readtoken()
    while (token != ""):
        print(token)
        token = s.readtoken()

    s.close()
main()
```

Comment: What do you expect from us? To write the whole program?

Comment: Don't you mean: `print(tokens[**i**])` instead of the 1?

Comment: yea its was suppose to be an "i", that time it actually scanned through the file, and no i dont want anyone to write it, I just cant get it to return the words as an array

Comment: its keeps saying global name "tokens" is undefined

Comment: You mean you can't get the `readTokens()` function to return an array? Consider python's `readlines()` function

Comment: @user3331010 the "tokens is undefined" error is because you've got a type between `token` and `tokens`.

Comment: Okay I updated the program up above,So now Basically it prints the whole file with each word on one line, now would my next step be too loop the array?

Answer (score 2):

This is StackOverflow so there is **no** way you'll get someone to write the whole program for you ... I'll assume your question is more about the *how* to approach the problem and you're working in python

**Divide and conquer is your friend**

1. Read the lines of a file: [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)
2. Store the lines into an array: [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) or [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/python-read-file-line-by-line-into-array)
3. Loop through every element in the array: [Here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for)
4. Check to see if each string found contains a punctuation: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143769/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-python-string-is-a-substring-of-another-one)
5. If it contains a punctuation, remove it (I'll leave this one up to you)

Try the above  and come up with a more functional solution (your code currently looks like you're still learning certain core programming ideas). After that, you can look into making it faster/more readable, etc. It will help the community better if you detailed your attempts.

Comment: LOL Yea I definitely am a rookie, but those steps did help me find the right track, thanks

Comment: Glad it helped :). Once you have code that works (or is very close), you can search for similar threads of head down to codereview for more tricks [example, using regular expressions, using the `yield` functionality to make things shorter, etc.]. Or better yet, edit this question with the changes you've made for more guidance.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you read the whole file and the split it at all spaces:

```
def readTokens(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        return f.read().split()
```

Comment: I already know ow to read the file I just cant return words as an array from the file

Comment: Yes, like so: `words = readTokens("somefile.txt")` and then `for word in words:`.