# Find elements in a list

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a file and want to find elements within it.

```
import unittest
import json
import requests


class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def test_description(self):
        api_url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/mtthu'
        r = requests.get(api_url))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: The line self.assertTrue... is a https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions if you do not feel comfortable with that, you'd better expand it to a classical for loop notation, so that you can add your 'young' test.

Answer (score 1):

Add another line to test_description and use the `in` keyword:

```
self.assertTrue(any('young' in c['Description'] for c in charities))
```

see:

```
print(('young' in 'abc', 'young' in 'abc young'))
```

Comment: I think it should be c['Slogan']

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to fetch a list of all `Charities` containing
`'Make a Wish'` in the `Description`.

```
haveWish = [c for c in charities if c['Description'] == 'Make a Wish']
```

Then you can check if all of them have `'young'` in `Slogan`

```
self.assertTrue(all('young' in c['Slogan'] for c in haveWish))
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
self.assertTrue(any((c['Description'] == 'Make a Wish') and ('young' in c['Slogan']) for c in charities))
```

using "in" for checking substring
[check out this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143769/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-python-string-is-a-substring-of-another-one)