# How to find string as a part of key value in list of dict?

Tags: python-3.x, django-2.1

In list of dictionaries I would like to find key value containg string.

```
markets = [
    {'symbol': 'BTC/AUD', 'baseId': 'bitcoin'},
    {'symbol': 'USD/AUD', 'baseId': 'dollar'},
    {'symbol': 'EUR/AUD', 'baseId': 'euro'},
    {'symbol': 'ETH/BTC', 'baseId': 'eth'},
]

s = 'BTC'
```

I would like to find in symbol values dicts containing a string.
For example:
Searching for s in markets symbols should return folowing list of dicts:

```
found = [
    {'symbol': 'BTC/AUD', 'baseId': 'bitcoin'},
    {'symbol': 'ETH/BTC', 'baseId': 'eth'},
]
```

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a given Python string is a substring of another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143769/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-python-string-is-a-substring-of-another-one)

Comment: Could you explain why question is downvoted?

Comment: Sorry I do not know...I did not downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
found = []
for market in markets:
    if s in market['symbol']:
        found.append(market)
return found
```

The above code should return a list of markets containing the value you're looking for. You can also condense this into a one liner:

```
found = [market for market in markets if s in market['symbol']]
```

Comment: I compared timing on your solution and Zeecka. On list with 1800 dictionaries time for your solution was 0.0004906654357910156
and for Zeecka solution - 0.0015139579772949219 so I marked your solution as accepted answer. Thank you both for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either:

```py
found = []
for m in markets:
    for l in m.values():
        if s in l:
            found.append(m)
```

or

```py
found = [m for m in markets for l in m.values() if s in l]
```