# how to detect a string in a variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
x = input("enter input: ")

if x == "hello":
    print ("it does")
```

How would I detect if x has hello stored even if it has other charaters/strings?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a given Python string is a substring of another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143769/how-do-i-check-if-a-given-python-string-is-a-substring-of-another-one)

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Please note that  [asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Answer (score 0):

This is as simple as using the `in` keyword.

```py
x = "123hellomore"
if "hello" in x:
    print("Hi there")
```

This only detects `hello`, if it is unobstructed so still in one word (not like "**hel*lo")

Comment: Thank you lighstack I appreciate it.

Comment: I'd be happy about an upvote if I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

If entered input is single string then x below will be array of one element, if entered input is space separated strings (string of strings) then x will be array of multiple strings, below code handles both options

```
x = input("Enter input: ").split()
for y in x:
   if y=="hello"
      print("it does")
```

Comment: I know this works but would you mind explaining how it works?